# unable to make image upload optional in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-upload

I have four images to upload. And all these four images are optional in my form.

I tried to make it optional but I could not solve my problem. Please check my code below and let me know any solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php


if(isset($_FILES))
{
    if(empty($_FILES['testfile']['name']))
    {
        echo 'no';
    }else{
        // do the form validation here
    }
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="testfile"/>
<input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

here is some test you can try i hope it helps

Comment: tried not working...Getting the same problem:  "you must select a file to upload"

Comment: @Ashutosh Maybe you are using a form_validation?? that is why .. don't use form validation if you don't want upload to be mandatory, otherwise it will check if for upload. OR you can put the form validation inside the code look at my edit.